# Convert a list<int> to a joined string of ints?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an int array with the value 3,99,6. How do i convert the array into the string `3,99,6` with linq?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
int[] list = new [] {3, 99, 6};
string s = string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

**Edit, C# 4.0**

With C# 4.0, there is another overload of [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx), which finally allows passing an `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<T>` directly. There is no need to create an Array, and there is also no need to call `ToString()`, which is called implicitly:

```
string s = string.Join(",", list);
```

With explicit formatting to string:

```
string s = string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.ToString(/*...*/));
```

Answer (score 17):

Stefan's solution is correct, and pretty much required for .NET 3.5. In .NET 4, there's an [overload of `String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) which takes an `IEnumerable<string>` so you can use:

```
string s = string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

or even just:

```
string s = string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: Is the ToString() needed? It seems to just do it on its own, as `String.Join(",", list);`