# String separating in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a list called `listitems` which contains information on items.

I want to separate each list item by a comma and put it in a string called `gh`

But when I use the following I get the output as :

`",a,b"` which is incorrect

but I want the output as `"a,b"`.

How can I modify the code ?

```
foreach(var a in listitems)
{
  gh = gh +"," + a;
}
```

Comment: You can look up into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610431/string-join-on-a-listint-or-other-type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string gh = String.Join(",", listitems); //
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use with [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) method.

> Concatenates the members of a constructed `IEnumerable<T>` collection of
>   type `String`, using the specified separator between each member.

```
string gh = String.Join(",", listitems);
```