# Join IDs from a list

Tags: c#

### The goal

Join each id of all elements from a List into a concatenated string like `1, 2, 3`.

### The problem

In my application there is a method whose its only parameter is of `string` type and I want to pass a value like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` to it.

Those values (`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`) will be sent to me by a `List<Product>` — I need to get the `id` of each element from this list.

How can I get these `ids` and concatenate them into a single string?

### What I've already tried

I've already tried the following code ([based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610431/string-join-on-a-listint-or-other-type)):

```
List<Products> sessionProducts = sessionStore.Get("ProductsSummary");
// ProductsSummary is the index of my Session.

string list = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts);

return Content(list);
```

But without success. When I access my view, the return is:

> MyApp.Models.Data.Products

### Techincal details

My .Net version is 4.5.

### Duplicated?

I think it isn't because I searched on Google and SO, but without success. Moreover, what I found doesn't helped me.

Comment: sessionProducts is a list of Products not string. Happy Friday!

Comment: @sza:  Why does that matter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
string list = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(p => p.id));
```

This uses the [generic version of string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx), as well as `Enumerable.Select` to convert from your Product collection to an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out the cause of his problem was that he was attempting to join instances of the `Product` type rather than strings. The select is required because it does a projection, for each product it returns the products id property which is a string.

Answer (score 2):

The output you're seeing is the result of calling `ToString` on the `Products` object and it appears it hasn't been overridden.

You either need to override the `ToString` of `Products` or choose the `id` property:

```
string list = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(product => product.id));
```

Comment: Missing a closing `)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a select statement in your `string.Join`:

```
List<Products> sessionProducts = sessionStore.Get("ProductsSummary");
string list = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(p => p.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a list of Ids to `string.Join`, like this:

```
string joinedIds = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(p => p.Id))
```

Otherwise, `ToString()` is called and that is why you're seeing that particular string.

Comment: what are you assigning it to.. ? string, list..?? you're just calling a method here look at `Reed Copsey's` answer he's assigning it to a string

Comment: @DJKRAZE His code would just be a drop in replacement for the join from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Because everyone else gave you the `.Select()` answer here is the other option. Override the ToString function on `Products` so when join attempts to join them it will use the id instead of the class name

```
public class Products
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string override ToString()
    {
        return this.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this

```
MyApp.Models.Data.Products
```

because you are passing it `List<Products>` and string.Join is calling `.ToString()` on your object. whereas you need to pass ids like this

```
string list = string.Join(", ", sessionProducts.Select(x=>x.id));
```