# depending on var count build string

Tags: c#

I have `List<string> num`.  Depending on count of num, I need to build a string like:

if num consists of `561924630638`

```
{"formType":"Status", "postDataList":[{"textWithMentions":{"text":"gogogo"}},{"imageData":{"imageIds":["561924630638"], "typeAndSizes":["561924630638,0,300,290"]}}], "news":false, "toStatus":true}
```

if num consists of `561924630638` and `561924630894`

```
{"formType":"Status", "postDataList":[{"textWithMentions":{"text":"gogogo"}},{"imageData":{"imageIds":["561924630638","561924630894"], "typeAndSizes":["561924630638,0,300,290","561924630894,0,300,290"]}}], "news":false, "toStatus":true}
```

Comment: So what's your question? If it's to ask how to write code for it, you need to show us what you have tried. (Show your code above.)

Comment: You could use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610431/string-join-on-a-listint-or-other-type

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> _num;
List<string> num
{
   get
   {
      return _num;
   }
   set
   {
      _num = value;

      // Check the value here and do what you need
      if (_num.Contains("561924630638"))
      { } 
      else if (_num.Contains("561924630638") && _num.Contains("561924630894"))
      { } 
   }
}
```