# How to get a comma between items in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my View, I want to display Guest Id's seperated by a comma but I don't know how. Right now it looks like the image below. 16 and 17 are Id's from seperate guests. This is confusing.

[image]

My model looks like this:

```
public class Guest
{
    [Key]
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
    //Vreemde sleutel van Reservation
    public Int32? ReservationId { get; set; }
}
```

The controller generating the View looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_reservationrepository.GetAllReservations());
    }

public IQueryable GetAllReservations()
    {
        return db.Reservations.Include(r => r.spot).Include(r => r.User).Include(r => r.Guests);

    }
```

My View displaying the Id's looks like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guests)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

How can I make the guest Id's seperated by a comma?

Comment: What does your view code look like? I tend to think that the view code would be the only relevant piece of code for this issue :-)

Comment: You may want to have a look at String.Join as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610431/string-join-on-a-listint-or-other-type)

Comment: @chiccodoro yes I have added the view code to the OP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view has a collection of `Guest` objects (let's call it `Model.Guests` for now), then you can join the IDs into a delimited string:

```
@string.Join(",", Model.Guests.Select(g => g.GuestId))
```

Or, depending on the semantic context of the view model (if it's just for the view and not really a business model) then you might even put that on the model itself:

```
public string GuestIDs
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(",", Guests.Select(g => g.GuestId));
    }
}
```

and just bind the view to that property:

```
@Model.GuestIDs
```

Comment: Thank you! I have it like this now and this works: `@string.Join(",", item.Guests.Select(g => g.GuestId))`

Answer (score 2):

You can include a comma by joining it with the result like

```
@string.Join(",", Model.Guests.Select(g => g.GuestId))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the list of `<int>` by comma like this.

```
// old way
List<int> list = ...;
string.Join(",", list.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());

// new way - just pass in list, no need to call .ToArray()
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: Note that the `ToArray()` method call is unnecessary.

Comment: You don't need the .ToArray() when using String.Join().  One overload (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts IEnumerable<string>.