# "Index 0 is either negative or above row count" error C#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I need help too much.

I am getting the following exception:

> Index 0 is either negative or above row count error

I researched in stackoverflow and google, but I couldn't fixed error.

My code:

```
if (lb_Gmy.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    string gmyquery = "Select * from tblA (nolock) where ParameterID = 2 and Status = 1";
    DataView dataw = new DataView(ReturnTable(gmyquery));

    foreach (string item in lb_Gmy.SelectedItems)
    {
        dataw.RowFilter = "Value = '" + item + "'";
        gmy += dataw[0]["ParamValue"].ToString() + ",";
    }

    gmy = gmy.Substring(0, gmy.Length - 1);
}
```

But I am not getting an error in this code:

```
if (lb_Fg.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    string gmyquery = "Select * from tblA (nolock) where ParameterID = 2 and Status = 1";
    DataView dataw = new DataView(ReturnTable(gmyquery));

    foreach (string item in lb_Fg.SelectedItems)
    {
        dataw.RowFilter = "Value = '" + item + "'";
        findingGmy += dataw[0]["ParamValue"].ToString() + ",";
    }

    findingGmy = findingGmy.Substring(0, findingGmy.Length - 1);
}
```

They are looking same. I'm confused so much. Where is the problem? Tell me please.

Comment: what is lb_Gmy/lb_Fg .you may be getting in this only.where are you getting error.Need to give some more details

Comment: they are listbox. I am getting error into foreach loop

Comment: Just a side note, you may be able to switch out your entire foreach-loop and the substring that follows to clean up, by using `string.join()`. Take a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610431/string-join-on-a-listint-or-other-type).

Answer (score 2):

Which means the DataView, `dataw` is Empty(the query returns no records) . So you have to Check for Empty before accessing the Value from it.

```
DataView dataw = new DataView(ReturnTable(gmyquery));
if (dataw!=null && dataw.Count > 0)
{
    // Your code here
}
```