# Concatenate dictionary value from key[0] - key[n]

Tags: c#, linq

can anyone help me with this scenario. So I have a dictionary of any size. What i would like is to concatenate the values from key[0] to key[5] let's say into a new dictionary key

So EX having the following

> {[0], "string1"} {[1], "string2"} {[2], "string3"} {[3], "string4"}
>   {[4], "string5"} {[5], "string6"}

would like to have a new dictionary lets say something like

> {[0], "string1;string2;string3"} {[1], "string4;string5;string6"}

what i have is a list of Accounts first i convert the list to a dictionary

```
  var keyVal = _request.AccountNames.Select((self, index) => new { self, index }).ToDictionary(key => key.index, value => value.self);
```

and after i want to create the new dictionary but have no idea how, what i can do is concat all key value into one large string.
I could calculate the indexOf of the ";" and split the list where is needed but i prefer to use a dictionary.

```
 keyVal .Select(x => x.Value).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ";" + s2);
```

Thank you.

Comment: use String.Join() function.refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3610448/7036750

Comment: `_request.AccountNames.Select((self, index) => new { self, index }).GroupBy(e => e.index/3, e => e.self).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(";", g))`

Comment: Sometimes is better implement your logic in a for loop; The linq performance is not so good. Make a test and verify if this is the case.